# Save contour as image

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, scikit-image

I am trying to convert a folder to show the contours of each image. The code will show the image when I plot it, but not save it to image. How can I save it to an image ?

Current error message :

```
ValueError: 'arr' does not have a suitable array shape for any mode.


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from PIL import Image

i=0
directory_in_str='C:\\directory'
directory_output='C:\\output_directory'
for file in os.listdir(directory_in_str):
        print(file)

        # read image to array
        im = array(Image.open(join(directory_in_str,file)).convert('L'))

        # show contours with origin upper left corner
        im = plt.contour(im, levels=[100], colors='black', origin='image')

        scipy.misc.imsave(directory_output +'image' + str(i) + '.jpg', im)
        i+=1

print('done')
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The [`imsave` function](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave.html) is meant to be used with numpy arrays.

As an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.rand(10,10)
plt.imsave("test.png", arr)
```

Here you want to save the matplotlib figure instead. 
As stated in @lelouchkato's answer, this would be done using the [`plt.savefig`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) function.

Mind that you need to save to an existing directory, so you probably want an additional backspace `\\` in your path

```
plt.savefig(directory_output +'\\image' + str(i) + '.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following `plt.savefig` function.

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html